# Deepl API reponse untranslated

Tags: javascript, node.js, translation, deepl

I'm trying to use DeepL API to translate some text files.
When I make a request with a text file that has fewer than 3 words, the API response is correct and it gives me back the translated text file. However, when I try to do the same thing with a text file that has more than 3 words, the API doesn't translate anything and responds to the request with the text file untranslated.

I'm just started to learn about API, so anybody can help me with this?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

// Replace [yourAuthKey] with your actual DeepL API authorization key
const deepLAuthKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

// User Inputs
const sourceLang = 'PT';
const targetLang = 'EN-US';
const inputFilePath = './root_text.txt';
const outputFilePath = './translated_text.txt';

// Function to read the text file
function readTextFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

// Function to write the translated text to a file
function writeTextFile(filePath, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(filePath, data, 'utf8', (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
}

// Function to translate the text
async function translateText(text, sourceLang, targetLang) {
    try {
        // Prepare the request data
        const requestData = {
            text: encodeURIComponent(text),
            source_lang: sourceLang,
            target_lang: targetLang,
        };

        // Make a POST request to the DeepL API
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/translate',
            requestData,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `DeepL-Auth-Key ${deepLAuthKey}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
            }
        );

        // Extract the translated text from the API response
        const translatedText = decodeURIComponent(response.data.translations[0].text);
        return translatedText;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Translation error:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

// Run the functions
readTextFile(inputFilePath)
    .then(async (text) => {
        // Call the translateText function
        const translatedText = await translateText(text, sourceLang, targetLang);
        console.log('Original Text:', text);
        console.log('Translated Text:', translatedText);
        return writeTextFile(outputFilePath, translatedText);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Translated text saved to:', outputFilePath);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
```